# Mysql group columns and sort in Alphabetical order - PHP invoved

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two columns titled word and word2. They each have a word listed inside. My goal is to combine word and word2. If a word is repeating then combine these words as ONE WORD and then place all the words in alphabetical order ([see website](https://livinghisword.org/articlestagresults.php?word=Persecution)).

[image]

1. Need for word and word2 to combine into one word only if the word are repeating.
2. Need for them to be in alphabetical order

This code was given to me and now I need help because I am adding another column but I do not know how to get the mysql and php code to work together to have ONE NAME SHOWING and put them in ALPHABETICAL ORDER. Please [visit my website here](https://livinghisword.org/articlestagresults.php?word=Persecution) to see what I am referring to, thank you.

**HERE IS MY CODE** - Can you please **respond with code**. If I new the code I would not be here, any help would be great.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT word, word2 FROM articles");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) { 
$link = $row['link'];
$word_array = explode(", ", $row['word']); $unique_word_array = array_unique($word_array);
asort($unique_word_array);

foreach($unique_word_array as $key) 
{ 
        echo "<div class='cloudbox tag'><a href = '../../articlestagresults.php?word=" . $key . "'> " . $key . "</a></div>"; }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `union`:

```
select word
from articles
union
select word2
from articles
order by word;
```

`union` removes duplicates.

Comment: This is great if your using mysql only. This does not work with the php coding. It only recognizes the first column named word and ignores the second column named word2. I need to know how to code the php where it recognizes both columns, thank you

Comment: @Jennifer . . . This creates one column with all the values of the two columns.  That is how I interpret "If a word is repeating then combine these words as ONE WORD and then place all the words in alphabetical order ".  Perhaps you should provide sample data and desired results, if this isn't the intention of your question.